# Updating Thunderbolt on Ubuntu XPS13

Tags: 18.04, updates, xps, thunderbolt

I am trying to run the update below:

[image]

And this is the message I get:

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that [Thunderbold apparently can only be successfully updated when a Thunderbold device is connected to the computer](https://github.com/dell/thunderbolt-nvm-linux/issues/8). Thus, connect a Thunderbold device and try again.

No Thunderbold device available and annoyed by the pop-up? Then disable the service that checks for firmware updates:

`sudo systemctl disable fwupd`

To reverse the change, enable the service again:

`sudo systemctl enable fwupd`